# Cisco NTP Clock is unsynchronized

Tags: cisco, switch, ntp

I have two internap NTP server and i set them up on Cisco Router but this is what i am getting.

```
R1#show ntp associations

  address         ref clock       st   when   poll reach  delay  offset   disp
*~10.1.1.50       129.6.15.28      2      4     64   377  0.764 -26.612  1.962
+~10.1.1.51       129.6.15.28      2     10     64   377  0.766 -18.581  1.946
 * sys.peer, # selected, + candidate, - outlyer, x falseticker, ~ configured
```

Status:

```
R1#show ntp status
Clock is unsynchronized, stratum 3, reference is 10.1.1.50
nominal freq is 250.0000 Hz, actual freq is 250.0000 Hz, precision is 2**10
ntp uptime is 85000 (1/100 of seconds), resolution is 4000
reference time is DB1E7441.2B020CC0 (12:22:25.168 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
clock offset is -27.2765 msec, root delay is 78.64 msec
root dispersion is 37.11 msec, peer dispersion is 1.95 msec
loopfilter state is 'FREQ' (Drift being measured), drift is 0.000000000 s/s
system poll interval is 64, last update was 37 sec ago.
```

But its showing correct time, Why `show ntp status` showing  `unsynchronized` ??

```
R1#show clock
.12:23:41.217 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016
```

## EDIT

```
!
ntp server vrf Mgmt-intf 10.1.1.50
ntp server vrf Mgmt-intf 10.1.1.51
!
clock timezone EST -5 0
clock summer-time EDT recurring
!
```

Question:

We have two ntp server `NTP1` & `NTP2` and NTP server syncing time with public NTP server, should i put two different public NTP server list on NTP1 & NTP2 server or public NTP list supposed to be same on both ntp1 and ntp2 server, what is the best practice for that?

## UPDATE:

Output:

```
R1#show ntp associations detail
10.1.1.50 configured, ipv4, sane, valid, stratum 2
ref ID 199.102.46.79  , time DB1E94EB.26269DEA (14:41:47.149 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
our mode client, peer mode server, our poll intvl 512, peer poll intvl 512
root delay 29.98 msec, root disp 33.12, reach 377, sync dist 54.98
delay 0.14 msec, offset 27.2130 msec, dispersion 1.08, jitter 0.97 msec
precision 2**19, version 4
assoc id 37176, assoc name 10.5.3.60
assoc in packets 154, assoc out packets 155, assoc error packets 0
org time 00000000.00000000 (19:00:00.000 EST Thu Dec 31 1899)
rec time DB1E95F8.319EEF80 (14:46:16.193 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
xmt time DB1E95F8.319EEF80 (14:46:16.193 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
filtdelay =     0.84    0.84    0.85    0.14    0.15    0.84    0.84    0.79
filtoffset =   27.25   27.41   26.89   27.21   27.35   27.18   27.11   27.16
filterror =     0.97    1.00    1.03    1.06    1.09    1.12    1.15    1.18
minpoll = 6, maxpoll = 10

10.1.1.51 configured, ipv4, our_master, sane, valid, stratum 2
ref ID 199.102.46.79  , time DB1E937E.A19C2C7C (14:35:42.631 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
our mode client, peer mode server, our poll intvl 512, peer poll intvl 512
root delay 29.86 msec, root disp 24.49, reach 377, sync dist 47.72
delay 0.16 msec, offset 9.3404 msec, dispersion 1.08, jitter 0.97 msec
precision 2**19, version 4
assoc id 37177, assoc name 10.5.3.61
assoc in packets 154, assoc out packets 154, assoc error packets 0
org time 00000000.00000000 (19:00:00.000 EST Thu Dec 31 1899)
rec time DB1E959A.2D3A68F6 (14:44:42.176 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
xmt time DB1E959A.2D3A68F6 (14:44:42.176 EDT Wed Jun 29 2016)
filtdelay =     0.83    0.80    0.84    0.16    0.84    0.17    0.83    0.78
filtoffset =    9.09    9.22    9.28    9.34    9.49    9.24    9.60    8.85
filterror =     0.97    1.00    1.03    1.06    1.09    1.12    1.15    1.18
minpoll = 6, maxpoll = 10
```

Comment: What is the NTP configuration?

Comment: You may want to include the NTP configurations for your NTP servers. Normally, you would use multiple public NTP servers for your two NTP servers, and let the NTP servers decide which public NTP server is best to use. You can peer your two NTP servers so that they agree with each other, but your NTP clients should not be set as peers with your NTP servers, and your NTP servers will not be able to peer with public NTP servers..

Comment: We have `mikrotik` NTP server, it has no fancy configuration. very simple to setup

Comment: Try and configure the time manually after you have configured NTP.  It's been a while but seems like I remember having a similar issue and the fix was to manually set the time to be close to true.  If the time was too far invalid, it would never synch.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

According to Cisco, loss of synchronization occurs when the IOS device cannot trust the NTP server. It may be due to packet drops from network congestion.

Cisco has a document specific to NTP troubleshooting:

[Network Time Protocol (NTP) Issues Troubleshooting and Debugging Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-time-protocol-ntp/116161-trouble-ntp-00.html)

> **Loss of Synchronization**
>
> Loss of synchronization might occur if the dispersion and/or delay
>   value for a server goes very high. High values indicate that the
>   packets are taking too long to get to the client from the server/peer
>   in reference to the root of the clock. So, the local machine cannot
>   trust the accuracy of the time present in the packet, because it does
>   not know how long it took for the packet to get here.
>
> NTP is meticulous about time and will not synchronize with another
>   device it cannot trust or cannot adjust in a way so that it can be
>   trusted.
>
> If there is a saturated link and buffering occurs along the way, the
>   packets get delayed as they come to the NTP client. So, the timestamp
>   contained in a subsequent NTP packet can occasionally vary a lot, and
>   the local client cannot really adjust for that variance.
>
> NTP does not offer a method to turn off the validation of these
>   packets unless you use SNTP (Simple Network Time Protocol). SNTP may
>   not be much of an alternative because it is not widely supported in
>   software.
>
> If you experience loss of synchronization, you should check the links:
>
> - Are they saturated?
> - Are there any kinds of drops in your wide-area network (WAN) links
> - Is encryption occurring?
>
> Monitor the reach value from the **show ntp associations detail**
>   command. The highest value is 377. If the value is 0 or low, NTP
>   packets are being received intermittently, and the local client goes
>   out of sync with the server.
>
> **debug ntp validity**
>
> The **debug ntp validity** command indicates whether the NTP packet
>   failed sanity or validity checks and reveals the reason for the
>   failure. Compare this output to the sanity tests specified in RFC1305
>   that are used in order to test the NTP packet received from a server.

Comment: Check i have updated output of command, it is showing `377`

Comment: Did you check what the problem is with the debug command? there is a table in the document that will pinpoint the problem based on the results.

Comment: my cisco ASR1006 doesn't support that `debug` command :( one more thing after few hours now my it is showing `Clock is synchronized, stratum 3, reference is 10.1.1.51` just question why its sync with `10.1.1.51` only why not `10.1.1.50`

Comment: You could try `debug ntp events`.

Comment: It will select the best NTP server with which to synchronize. You put in multiple NTP servers and let it pick the best one.

Comment: You can go through multiple synchronized/non-synchronized cycles all the time, depending on the congestion present on the network.

Comment: @Satish, if your NTP servers are going through the WAN to get to public NTP servers, you may as well dump them since you say they have no special features, and just use the WAN routers as your NTP servers for the network equipment. You can use the access or distribution switches as the NTP servers for the hosts.

Comment: is that good idea to run NTP on Router? Doesn't it cost CPU? also how Router will get sync with external NTP?

Comment: It costs the same CPU for a router to sync to an external server as it does to sync to an internal server. You can sync to any NTP server for which you have an IP address (and any necessary authentication). You can, and should, place an ACL to block all NTP except for the NTP servers to which you want to synchronize.

Comment: Hmm! but i heard when you configure `ntp master` command router use its internal hardware clock which is not stable.

Comment: Not exactly. You use that when there is no authoritative source. "_Some routers contain a battery-powered hardware clock that tracks the date and time across system restarts and power outages. The hardware clock is always used to initialize the software clock when the system is restarted. If no other source is available, the hardware clock can be considered to be an authoritative source of time and be redistributed via NTP or VINES time service. If NTP is running, the hardware clock can be updated periodically from NTP, compensating for the inherent drift in the hardware clock._"

Comment: "_Use the following command in global configuration mode if you want the system to be an authoritative NTP server, even if the system is not synchronized to an outside time source: `Router(config)# ntp master [stratum]`_" You don't need to use the command if the router uses an NTP server for the router to _be_ an NTP server.